# Что означает html конструкция ?

Tags: html

Что означает этот код ?

```
.show-grid .show-grid [class*="span"] {
...
}
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov

Answer (score 3):

во-первых это css-правило, которое применятся примерно к следующему html:

```
<div class="show-grid">
  <div class="show-grid">
    <div class='spanSomething'> // атрибут class содержит строку 'span'

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: то есть это применимо ко всем спанам, любым спанам ?

Comment: это применимо ко всем тегам с классами содержащими строку `span` и имеющим 2 родительских элемента с классом `show-grid`